# How do I stub a File object with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

I have the following in a spec:

```
before do 
  @item = Item.new( title: "Lorem ipsum", 
    image: File.new(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'rails.png')))
end
```

The associated specs take about 30 seconds to run but when I remove `image: File.new()` from the hash, my tests run in under 1 second!

So `File.new()` is adding a load to my specs and I'd like to stub it if possible, but when I try this:

```
image: File.stub(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'rails.png')))
```

I see the following error in my test output:

```
 Failure/Error: image: File.stub(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'rails.png'))) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `to_sym' for #<Pathname:0xae767d8>
```

I would appreciate any advice here. FWIW, image upload is handled by paperclip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but this is not mocking a file. You want to fabricate an object and attach a real file to it – that's not a mock and neither of these sollutions mocks a file object.

You absolutely positively should use a gem to fabricate test data, like [factory girl rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails), or [fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/).

..and when you do Tom L's answer is the best one: use `fixture_file_upload`

Comment: From what I gathered from how fixture_file_upload works in Rails, what it does is NOT fabricate some "test image file". It links to actual image files (for example, [this one](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8015c2c2cf5c8718449677570f372ceb01318a32/actionmailbox/test/fixtures/files/avatar1.jpeg)) and uses fixture_file_upload as a standard way to use those REAL images in tests. 

Different modules have different test files ("fixtures")

This answer seemed to imply that the image should be mocked using Factory Girl Rails or Fabrication. Neither will help with mocking files.

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like this:

```
@item = Item.new( title: "Lorem ipsum")
file = double('file', :size => 0.5.megabytes, :content_type => 'png', :original_filename => 'rails')
@item.stub(image).and_return(file)
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at fixture_file_upload in the Rails API:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload

Answer (score 1):

It also possible to stub attachments like this:
Add it into spec/support

```
module PaperclipStub
  def stub_paperclip_attachment(model, attachment)
    model.any_instance.stub(attachment.to_sym).and_return File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'file.png')
    model.any_instance.stub("#{attachment}_file_name".to_sym).and_return File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'file.png')
  end
end
```

In spec_helper.rb

```
config.include PaperclipStub # Include custom paperclip_attachment stub
```

And use it in specs:

```
it "should be valid" do
    stub_paperclip_attachment(Image, :image)
    Image.new.should be_valid
  end
```